# Fractional derivative of $e^{-x^2/2}$ using Fourier transform and Taylor series

Tags: fourier-analysis, partial-derivative, taylor-expansion

I am not familiar with fractional calculus, so I want to know what I am doing wrong.

The convention I use

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}e^{-i k x}dx=\sqrt{2 \pi}e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}$$

I am assuming this should work

$$\frac{d^{0.5}}{dx^{0.5}}\rightarrow\sqrt{i k}=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\sqrt k$$

And inverse transformation

$$\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\sqrt k\sqrt{2 \pi}e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}\rightarrow\frac{1}{2 \pi}\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{2 \pi}\int^\infty_{-\infty}\sqrt k\,e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}e^{i k x}dk=\frac{1+i}{2\sqrt \pi}\bigg(\int ^\infty_0 \sqrt k e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}e^{i k x}dk-i\int ^\infty_0 \sqrt k e^{-\frac{k^2}{2}}e^{-i k x}dk\bigg)$$

Since I am not an integration mastermind, mathematica evaluates this to be

$$\frac{\sqrt{2} \Gamma \left(\frac{3}{4}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{3}{4};\frac{1}{2};-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)-2 x \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right) \, _1F_1\left(\frac{5}{4};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)}{2^{3/4} \sqrt{\pi }}$$

And mathematica input would be (should you want to look at it yourself)

```
1/(2^(3/4)
   Sqrt[\[Pi]]) (Sqrt[2]
     Gamma[3/4] Hypergeometric1F1[3/4, 1/2, -(x^2/2)] - 
   2 x Gamma[5/4] Hypergeometric1F1[5/4, 3/2, -(x^2/2)])
```

Which looks like

[image]

This looks about right to me.

But I cannot achieve the same result using the taylor series.

$$e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=\sum _{n=0}^{20} \frac{(-1)^n }{2^n n!}x^{2n}$$

After partially differentiating

$$\sum _{n=0}^{20} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2 n-0.5} \Gamma (2 n+1)}{\left(2^n n!\right) \Gamma (2 n+0.5)}$$

Which doesn't quite make sense

[image]

Comment: For one thing, the derivative of a constant should be zero, even a fractional one. You have some negative power of $x$ instead. Also, what do you expect your series formula to do when $x$ is negative?

Comment: Right now I just want $x>0$ to work, after that, I can try to understand what happens for $x<0$ also: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html disagrees with you. it says that the derivative of a constant is a function

Comment: Your question is unclear. You wrote down two different functions, observed that their plots are different. Of course they are, what did you expect?

Comment: They are supposed to be the same. They were obtained by partially differentiating using fourier transform and taylor series. I have made a mistake in computing at least one of them. I want to learn what I did wrong.

Comment: You used two different ideas of what it means to "partially differentiate". Again, what is the reason to expect the second series to be the same as the first function? Clearly, the power series approach depends on the choice of the base point ($0$ in this case) while the first one doesn't.

Comment: taylor series for exponential function converges

Comment: @1999 how would you compute $\frac{d^{0.5}}{dx^{0.5}}e^{-x^2/2}$ and how would you apply the same method to a taylor expansion.